# QPlainTextEdit: subprocess segmentation fault using threads

Tags: python, pyqt, segmentation-fault, subprocess, pyside

### Segmentation Fault in subprocess.stdout while displaying on QPlainTextEdit

Hi,
I am starting a thread to the function shown and streaming its result to a QTextEdit object in the thread. The function sometimes crashes with a segmentation fault for unknown reasons.

```
self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
self.thread = Thread(target = runcmd, args = ("make dc",))
self.thread.start()
self.thread.join()
def runcmd(self,cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1)
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        self.plainTextEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        self.plainTextEdit.insertPlainText(line.strip())
    process.terminate()
```

The

> make dc

command is a call to the design compiler synthesis tool. If I try to print the

> line

variable instead of writing to the plainTextEdit Object the thread runs fine, displaying the result in the terminal window. Any help/advice is welcome......
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can't use QT things from a python thread. Your options:

- Send the data back from the thread to your main program, using a `queue.Queue` or some other similar synchronization object. Then the main program adds the data to the text widget. [Documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue)
- Use a QThread, which is the QT equivalent of threads. [Documentation here](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QThread.html).

Comment: I tried with QThread ... But ended up with the same result... :(

Comment: It is not a **direct replacement** @DhanushSrinivasa - you have to move the objects between the QThreads - read the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the Qt GUI from another thread. Fortunately for us, Qt gave us signals, and PyQt gave us `pyqtSignal`, just for this situation. There are a few ways to do it, but I prefer the following style.

```
class YourClass(QtCore.QObject):
    appendSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(YourClass, self).__init__()
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.appendSignal.connect(self.reallyAppendToTextEdit)
        self.appendToTextEdit = self.appendSignal.emit
        self.thread = Thread(target = runcmd, args = ("make dc",))
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.join()
    def reallyAppendToTextEdit(self, txt):
        self.plainTextEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        self.plainTextEdit.insertPlainText(txt)
    def runcmd(self,cmd):
        process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1)
        while True:
            line = process.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            self.appendToTextEdit(line.strip())
        process.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `subprocess.Popen()` you should use `QProcess` which is GUI friendly so it is not necessary to use a new thread.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import shlex


class LogWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LogWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        lay.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.runcmd("make dc")

    def runcmd(self, cmd):
        process = QProcess(self)
        process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardOutput)
        process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardError)
        program, *arguments = shlex.split(cmd)
        process.start(program, arguments)

    def onReadyReadStandardOutput(self):
        process = self.sender()
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(str(process.readAllStandardOutput()))

    def onReadyReadStandardError(self):
        process = self.sender()
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(str(process.readAllStandardError()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LogWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```